# Working with sets, set difference, union and intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am asked to prove that
 $$ A \setminus (B \cap C) = (A\setminus B) \cup (A\setminus C). $$

However I am only finding this to be not true. How would I prove this?

Comment: How did you find that this is not true? (Seems true to me).

Comment: Typically, to show that two sets are equal, you'll show that each is a subset of the other. Pick some $x$ in the set on the left, and show it's also in the set on the right. Repeat in the other direction.